# C - Reading multiline from text file

Tags: c, file, text

This is most likely a dumb question!
I have a text file filled with random numbers and I would like to read these numbers into an array.

My text file looks like this:

```
1231231 123213 123123
1231231 123213 123123
0

1231231 123213 123123
1231231 123213 123123
0
```

And so on.. The piece of numberse ends with `0`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
FILE *file = fopen("c:\\Text.txt", "rt");
char line[512];

if(file != NULL)
{
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(line, stdout);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

This does clearly not work, since I read each line into the same variable.

How can I read the lines and when the line gets the line where it ends with 0, then store that piece of text into an array?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want an array of strings ?

Comment: @Lars: You want the textual strings, rather than the acutal numbers?

Comment: @Kerrek SB - First of all, I need to read the piece of text, then when  piece of text has been read I woule like to tokenize it, I dont whant to tokenize the text piece before the hole pice have been read.

Comment: OK, but after tokenization do you want to parse the strings into numbers or just leave them as strings?

Comment: @Kerrek SB - I would like to parse them into numbers, and please se my uppdated comment above!

Comment: Alright. Well, I posted an example below; if you want the actual strings, then use `strdup` instead of `strtol`, and change the array base type from `int` to `char*` (and add an additional `free()` sweep at the end).

Answer (score 1):

You just have to store the numbers that you read from the file in some permanent storage! Also, you probably want to parse the individual numbers and obtain their numerical representation. So, three steps:

1. Allocate some memory to hold the numbers. An array of arrays looks like a useful concept, one array for each block of numbers.
2. Tokenize each line into strings corresponding to one number each, using `strtok`.
3. Parse each number into an integer using `atoi` or `strtol`.

Here's some example code to get you started:

```
FILE *file = fopen("c:\\Text.txt", "rt");
char line[512];

int ** storage;
unsigned int storage_size = 10; // let's start with something simple
unsigned int storage_current = 0;

storage = malloc(sizeof(int*) * storage_size); // later we realloc() if needed

if (file != NULL)
{
    unsigned int block_size = 10;
    unsigned int block_current = 0;

    storage[storage_current] = malloc(sizeof(int) * block_size); // realloc() when needed

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
    {
        char * tch = strtok (line, " ");
        while (tch != NULL)
        {
            /* token is at tch, do whatever you want with it! */

            storage[storage_current][block_current] = strtol(tch, NULL);

            tch = strtok(NULL, " ");

            if (storage[storage_current][block_current] == 0)
            {
                ++storage_current;
                break;
            }

            ++block_current;

            /* Grow the array "storage[storage_current]" if necessary */
            if (block_current >= block_size)
            {
                block_size *= 2;
                storage[storage_current] = realloc(storage[storage_current], sizeof(int) * block_size);
            }
        }

        /* Grow the array "storage" if necessary */
        if (storage_current >= storage_size)
        {
            storage_size *= 2;
            storage = realloc(storage, sizeof(int*) * storage_size);
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, you need to free the memory:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= storage_current; ++i)
    free(storage[i]);
free(storage);
```

Comment: I think you need to `s/int/storage/g` in a few places.

Comment: @user: Yep, spotted that already - thanks! Does `realloc` move the existing memory around?

Comment: It does. One thing to note with `realloc` is that `p=realloc(p,sz)` is  kind of an anti-pattern as the the code will leak if `p!=NULL` and `realloc` returns `NULL`. It probably won't matter much here though.

Comment: @user: Yes, that's an important point, and the real code should probably check all calls to `malloc()`/`realloc()`. I won't change the example though so as not to obscure the presentation, but you're absolutely right.

Comment: Is there ant this wrong with this: storage = malloc(sizeof(int*) * storage_size), becuase I get an error saying void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int **?

Comment: @Lars: Are you in C or in C++? In C you shouldn't have to cast the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: @Lars: I cannot reproduce that, `T * x = malloc(sizeof(T));` should work for any type `T`. What's your compiler? Anyway, you can add an explicit cast if you like. Are you including `stdlib.h`?

Comment: @Lars: That's not a C compiler, it's really just a C++ compiler. Please tag your question appropriately and think about your problem accordingly. Do you want a C++ solution?

Comment: @Kerrek SB - Yes i´m including stdlib.h

Comment: In C++ you have to cast pointers explicitly, so it's `T * x = (T*)malloc(...);`. But now this is getting ugly. Get a real C compiler if you want to write C programs.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - Sorry for the confusion, I know its C++ compiler but iam developing C, I need a C solution please.

Comment: @Lars: I gave you a C solution. Your problem is now that you don't have a C compiler to use it. What do you expect me to do?

Comment: @Kerrek SB - I´m getting a real C compiler and test the code there. Thank you very much for all the trouble.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - Hi again. I was wondering, does strtol really takes only two arguments or is it three?