# Read numbers from text file and use them as input

Tags: c, text, numbers

I have this text:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 1
```

I want to read the first 5 numbers from each line and then use them as inputs in a function.

I'm new to c and have only accomplished this code that doesn't do much, if anything really.

```
    int v,o;
    FILE *mydata;

    if ((mydata = fopen("testinputs.txt", "rt"))==NULL)
    {
        printf ("file can't be opened'\n");
        exit(1);}


    fclose(mydata);
```

How do i complete it?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024183/c-reading-multiline-from-text-file?rq=1

Comment: isn't there anything simpler? i find it a little hard to understand.

Comment: @user3032539: There have been 3 people who attempted to answer your question (well, technically, they did your work for you). All of the code contains comments explaining what the code does... if something in those answers is still unclear to you, perhaps comment on those answers, asking for clarification. If any of the answers solved your issue, please mark that answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small code to read character by character and store only the wanted numbers:

**C Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;                     // Character read from the file
    int cpt;                    // Counter (to get only 5 numbers per line)
    int i,j;                     // Array indexes
    int data[4][5];       // 2D integer array to store the data
    FILE *f;                // File

    if ((f = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL)       // Open the file in "read" mode
    {
        printf ("file can't be opened'\n");
        exit(255);
    }

    // Counter and indexes initialization
    cpt=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;

    // Read the file till the EOF (end of file)
    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        // If 5 numbers read, go to new line, first index in the data array and to the next line in the file
        if(cpt==5)
        {
            i++;
            cpt=0;
            j=0;
            while(c != '\n' && c != EOF)
                c=fgetc(f);
        }

        // If a number is read, store it at the right place in the array
        if(c>='0'&&c<='9')
        {
               // Convert character to integer (see ascii table)
            data[i][j] = c-'0';
            j++;
            cpt++;
        }
    }

        // Display the array
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            printf("%d ", data[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

And here is the **output:**

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
```

Now you can use your 2D array, for example if you want a variable `a` to have the 2nd line, 3rd number, you'd do : `a = data[1][2]`
Don't forget arrays start at index 0

Hope this helps...

Comment: Please, don't post a second answer: copy the contents of this answer, and add it to your first post... There's a little link at the bottom of your answer that says _"edit"_ :)

Comment: I just deleted the previous answer since it was more a comment than an answer, this one will be my only answer on the page. Thanks for advising me Elias ! :)

Comment: Don't mention it, and welcome to SO, BTW. I don't mean this in a bad way, but why read the file char per char? Of course, if the input is completely unpredictable, you have to, but here, using `fgets` + `sscanf` makes the code just so much easier to read/understand/maintain... not to mention: shorter and cleaner, and probably faster, too...

Comment: Since he's new to C, I thought it would have been nice to post a code to explain how to access each character, EOF, ascii->int conversion, etc... and with comments to explain. Furthermore, if the structure of a file is less organized, this code can be modified and reused.. But sure, for this particular problem it wasn't the best way, I meant it to be more academic

Comment: Well, if you want to be more academic, which is a good thing, you might want to change the `exit(-1)` to `exit (EXIT_FAILURE)` or `exit(255)`, given that an exit code is [defined as a value between 0 and 255](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html). This isn't codereview.stackexchange, of course, but I don't consider that second, nested `while(c != '\n' and c != EOF)` loop a nice solution either... and I'm sorry for being such a pedantic a**hole... I always get this way after a hard day at work :)

Comment: Didn't know for the exit code, I often use negative value of -1 to see that there was an error. Good to know, thanks for the information! Also, I don't pretend my codes to be perfect and I'm sure it can be much improved, but I was just trying to give a basis to start from...

Comment: Yes, I got that... I'm just too tired to make any sense in comments now, I actually started to type the last comment, just to point out that `exit(-1)` is actually `exit(255)`, and I wanted to apologize for being so darn pedantic. So: Sorry for nit-picking, and welcome to the site

Comment: No problem, I'm not offended. Thank you Elias !

Comment: Pleurk thank you very much you hepled me a lot, your answer's what i was looking for and the comments were helpful as well.One more question if you don't mind: if i have 2 more lines above the text i posted( the first only has the number 5 and the second only has the number 1) how do i skip them?I mean how do i not add them to the array?Thank you very much again.

Comment: You can skip the `n` first lines by getting each character one after another and checking if `c == '\n'`. You use a counter to count them, and when your counter reaches `n`, you know you have skipped the first n lines and you can start reading. So just after opening the file, add a simple loop which does it. I'm glad I could help you !

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming your file is called *"input.txt"*, then this is all you need to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_LEN 100
int main ( void )
{
    char line[LINE_LEN];
    int sum, i, read_cnt, numbers[5];//sum and i are there for my example usage
    FILE *in = fopen("input.txt", "r");//open file
    if (in == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File could not be opened\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while((fgets(line, LINE_LEN, in)) != NULL)
    {//read the line
        //scan 5 numbers, sscanf returns the number of values it managed to extract
        read_cnt = sscanf(
            line,
            "%d %d %d %d %d",
            &numbers[0],
            &numbers[1],
            &numbers[2],
            &numbers[3],
            &numbers[4]
        );
        //check to see if we got all 5 ints
        if (read_cnt != 5)
            printf("Warning: only read %d numbers\n", read_cnt);//whoops
        //just an example, let's add them all up
        for (sum= i=0;i<read_cnt;++i)
            sum += numbers[i];
        printf("Sum of numbers was: %d\n", sum);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

With this input.txt file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 2 2 2 2
1 23 2 3 4
12 23
```

This gives us the following output:

```
Sum of numbers was: 15
Sum of numbers was: 10
Sum of numbers was: 33
Warning: only read 2 numbers
Sum of numbers was: 35
```

That should be **more** than enough to get you started

Comment: +1 for `fgets()/sscanf()` and testing their results.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *datafile;
int main()
{
    char line[100],*ch;
    int count;

    datafile = fopen ( "my.txt", "r");

    while ( fgets(line , sizeof line , datafile) != NULL )//fgets reads line by line
    {
        count = 0;
        ch = strtok ( line , " ");
        while ( count < 5 && ch != NULL )
        {


            printf("%d ",*ch - 48 );//*ch gives ascii value
            //pass to any function

            count++;
            ch = strtok ( NULL, " ");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program passes integer by integer.

Comment: You don't need `strtok` here, `sscanf`. Converting numeric strings manually is all fine and dandy, but why would you bother? Why not simply use `atoi`?

Comment: Should I use atoi(ch) in the place of *ch-48 ?

Comment: Yes, because ATM, you assume all ints in the input will be < 10: `*ch-48` only converts a single char to a digit, whereas `atoi(ch)` can deal with input like "123", too. IMO, though, `sscanf` is the best tool for the job here

Comment: At The Moment (meaning: as it now stands, referring to your code) and In My Opinion, or IMHO (In My Honest Opinion)

Comment: Thanks, where can I get more like this :P

Comment: Why use `48` instead of `0`?